# javascript inside gridview not working under master page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

i want to select a row from gridview i am using following code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {               
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("javascript:__doPostBack('this','Select${0}')", e.Row.RowIndex));
            }
        }
```

It was working fine, but after using master page it has stops working.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see some more code but try adding this line to Page_Load of your MasterPage

```
ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
```

`__doPostBack` is registered via controls which normally do not cause a POST like LinkButton. Possibly, before migrating to MasterPage you may have one of those in your Page.

Comment: my problem get solved after using following code..

e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);